# Jaxb Error in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to create a java class from an Xml Schema available at a specified url.I am using netbeans Jaxb binding to achieve this .

i am getting the error :

```
    [ERROR] Property "Title" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
 line 481 of file:/C:/Users/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/xml-resources/jaxb/newbinding/tims.cisco.com/xsd/T2.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
line 38 of file:/C:/Users/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/xml-  resources/jaxb/newbinding/tims.cisco.com/xsd/xlink.xsd

failure in the XJC task. Use the Ant -verbose switch for more details
  C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\nbproject\xml_binding_build.xml:15: unable to parse the schema. Error messages should have been provided
```

I also checked a few posts which tell to change the But i dont know how to do it in netbeans..It would be helpful if somebody could give me  an example XML Schema and explain how to overcome this error in netbeans.

My example schema will be like this:

```
     <xs:schema xmlns="http://someurl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" targetNamespace="http://nsurl"   
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="3.7">
 <xs:include schemaLocation="./something.xsd" /> 
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="./xlink.xsd" /> 
 <xs:element name="elename">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Root element</xs:documentation> 
 </xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element ref="element1" minOccurs="0" /> 
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element ref="Element2" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
<xs:element ref="element3" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 

<xs:element ref="element4" /> 
<xs:element ref="element5" /> 
<xs:element ref="element6" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
<xs:element ref="Elemnt7" maxOccurs="unbounded" />  
<xs:element name="Member" type="MemberType" /> 
<xs:element ref="Path" /> 
</xs:choice>
<xs:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /> 
<xs:element name="ExecutionTime" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" /> 
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="msgID" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="optional" /> 
<xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:simpleLink" /> 
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am new to xml also.can somebody help me out to create classes in netbeans using jaxb or post pointers to manually create a java class for this schema.

The result should be like something given in the link:
  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/GenerateJavaSourceFromXMLSchemaXSD.htm

I am using an external binding file as follows

```
 <jxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               jxb:version="2.0">
      <jxb:bindings [schemaLocation="T2.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
      <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Title']">
       <jxb:property name="TitleElement"/>
      </jxb:bindings>
      </jxb:bindings>
      </jxb:bindings>
```

I used this external binding file while creating a jaxb binding in Netbeans but still it shows me the same error .It would be helpful if you could say what am i doing wrong
I need immediate help please do spare time to solve this.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your issues can be solved by changed the schema, for example in the way shown in [how to work around duplicate variables](http://www.xenta.nl/blog/2011/06/28/jaxb-and-how-to-work-around-duplicate-variables/).

Comment: I cant change the schema as it is something which is already existing and used by several others.So it would be helpful if you can tell how to use the external binding in NETBEANS 7.2